# Chrome extension : failed to load resource for external json

Tags: javascript, json, api, google-chrome-extension

I've been searching stackoverflow and google for an answer for that but I can't find anything... I'm still really new to javascript, so I'm a bit confused;

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Twitch Streams List",
  "description": "Find all the streams directly through Chrome",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
   "permissions": [
    "http://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?limit=20"
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": ["twitch.js"]
}
```

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Getting top streams from Twitch</title>
    <style>
      body {
        min-width: 350px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="twitch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

twitch.js

```
var streamGenerator = {
  /* url where to get the streams from */
  url: chrome.extension.getURL('http://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?limit=20'),

  /* go get the streams from the json at the url given */
  requestStreams: function() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', this.url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        var resp = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      }
    }
    xhr.send();
  },

  /* import the streams in the html page */
  showStreams: function (e) {
    var streams = resp.streams;
    var output = '<ul>';

    for (var i = 0; i < streams.length; i++) {
      output += '<li>' + streams[i].channel.display_name + ' - ' + streams[i].channel.viewers + ' - ' + streams[i].channel.game + '</li>';
    }

    output += '</ul>';
    console.log(output);
    document.body.appendChild(output);
  }
};

/* Run the script as soon as the popup is loaded */
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  streamGenerator.requestStreams();
});
```

Nothing appear in the popup, and the console says

```
Failed to load resource chrome-extension://dihpppnflhlpkehcgnjggjcipffmjlgp/http://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?limit=20
```

What to do???

Thanks

Comment: 'http://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?limit=20' isn't in your install directory, so don't pass it as an argument to chrome.extension.getURL.

Answer (score 2):

'api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?limit=20' isn't in your install directory, so don't pass it as an argument to `chrome.extension.getURL`.

That being said, XHR cannot fetch content cross domain.  You may want to see if they offer an alternative like JSONP.

Comment: Yes the string literal for the url by itself is the proper way, but your ajax requests will be blocked by the browser if you are requesting from a different domain, which I assume you are doing.

Comment: so what can I do to go through that cross domain security?

Comment: You could use a proxy server to fetch the JSON from the remote URL and then use that JSON as an argument for some method that exists in your extension (JSONP).  Do some googling, I'm sure you'll find a script that'll suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Worth noting:

http://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?limit=20 returns a 404

https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?limit=20 returns JSON

(SSL is required hy the twitch api)